# CSV file cannot be accessed via BufferedReader in Android

Tags: android, csv

I am trying to read a CSV file using BufferedReader in android. My program works perfectly fine in Java but when I try read those data from Android following error I get.

```
01-31 17:09:58.466: W/System.err(15912): java.io.FileNotFoundException:   
/Users/sabbir/Documents/workspace/TestCSV/src/file/input.csv: open failed: ENOENT (No 
such file or directory)
```

Following code I am using here.

```
public double getLongitudes() {
    BufferedReader br = null;
    String line = "";
    String cvsSplitBy = ";";
    String[] nextLine;
    double longitudes = 0;

    try {

        br = new BufferedReader(
                new FileReader(

"/Users/sabbir/Documents/workspace/TestCSV/src/file/input.csv"));
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            // use comma as separator

            String[] country = line.split(cvsSplitBy);
            longitudes = Double.parseDouble(country[5]);
            Log.d("worked", "worked");

            // System.out.println("Latitude " + longitudes);

        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (br != null) {
            try {
                br.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Done");

    return (longitudes);
}}
```

Any idea why its happening ??

Comment: this may be because you need to add this file in your project  resources  and need permission to 
android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Answer (score 1):

The path `/Users/sabbir/Documents/workspace/TestCSV/src/file/input.csv` is invalid. This looks like the path to a file on your computer rather than your Android device.  You need to push the file to your device or your emulated device and access it from there.  Even the Android emulator will not read files directly from your computer's filesystem.

Answer (score 1):

The .csv file needs to be in your project resources. You can copy the file into assets folder and read it this way

```
AssetInputStream asset_stream = (AssetInputStream)getAssets().open("input.csv");
InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(asset_stream);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);
```

This is one method that has worked for me before.

Another method would be to put the file into res/raw folder and access it

```
InputStream file = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.inputfile);
```

You can also refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/3851429/3092829

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Proper way to store your CSV in Android is:

```
("/sdcard/Android/data/filename.csv");
```

Answer (score 0):

So i have solved my problem.

```
public class ReadCSV {
BufferedReader br = null;
String line = "";
String cvsSplitBy = ";";
String[] nextLine;
String[] country;

AssetInputStream asset_stream = null;

public String[] getLatitude() {

    try {
        asset_stream = (AssetInputStream) MainActivity.getContext()
                .getAssets().open("Input.csv");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(asset_stream);

    Log.d("logg", "log" + reader);
    br = new BufferedReader(reader);
    Log.d("logg", "log" + br);

    try {
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            country = line.split(cvsSplitBy);

        }
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return country;

}
```

As you can see I am trying to get my latitude by returning it through country. But when I trying get it from another fragment class through this,

```
String[] lat;
lat = csv.getLatitude();
Log.d("", "" + lat);
```

Why I don't get latitude  back ?

Comment: what is the result you are getting when you try to print lat?

Comment: You should be using something like `Arrays.toString(lat)` to print your output. If not, you may end up printing the memory address of the array instead of the array elements